# Silverlight App(s) won't run on Windows 8 preview RSS

Tags: silverlight, windows-8

I tried an app I wrote that works on Win7 boxes. Using the Win8 Preview, IE just asks to rerun Silverlight Install. Same thing happens on the PlanetX demo game from the Silverlight site. Is there a trick to get the Win8 Preview to run it or is it true Silverlight is getting killed off for HTML5/Script (yuckkk!!@#$) If this is not true then MS needs to speak up LOUDLY. Writers are all over the Web with a Silverlight is dead/legacy story. Somebody please tell me now so I can cut my losses if I need to.
.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it using the debug tools?

Answer (score 8):

You can run Silverlight apps just fine on the Windows 8 preview. The Metro version of IE supports no plug-ins - not Silverlight, not Flash, not anything else. Just drop into the desktop (for example, click the Windows Explorer icon) and launch the non-metro version of IE. Silverlight will work fine. You can even install out of browser (OOB) applications and a launch tile will appear for them on the Metro start page.